# The delegates need the methods and attributes of the holder class

Tags: oop, inheritance, design-patterns, delegates

I have some entity, which depending on internals, may act in two ways. For example, my Connector class can operate as a HttpConnector and as a TCPConnector. The implementation of 'connect' method differs for these two 'engine' classes. Both of them share some common methods of Connector such as "openFileToTransfer(String fileName)" and share common attributes such as "folderWithFiles" etc. I need two find the best OOP design for this problem.

1) first way is delegation. I create Connector with TCPConnectorEngine and it works. The problem is that I need to share some settings and common methods. I dont want to copy paste them of course into each of the classes. I can provide common settings via constructor, which implies coding the same attributes two times, but sharing common methods is harder. May be I can inject Connector instance in each of them, but that looks ugly. May be I can provide a BaseClass for both of my ConnectorEngines, but this looks more complicated.

2) second way is inheritance. I just inherit TCPConnector from Connector and get all I need. But I suppose the 'engine' decision fits better for my task just because it fits better logically. It is really an engine of Connector, its not different types of Connector.. but may be I am wrong?

Which way you would choose and why?
I work with Java, if it matters for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pattern terminology, the question boils down to, how to implement a `Connection` interface properly:

1) Use a **facade** and then delegate to a **strategy**.

2) Or use an abstract base class and inherit with concrete implementation.

So in my **opinion 2** is a good solution, only in case the internal choreography or protocol of the chil classes is quite similar and they therefore can share a lot of structure and code, which is then captured in the base class.

If the concepts used internally are quite different, I think it is better to implement different **strategies**, instanciate those in a **facade** class and delegate to the **strategy** instances. If you want code reuse, e.g. for the settings, I would keep this concept in a different class, e.g. `ConnectionSettings` and inject that to the strategy instance from the facade.